# Google Code Jam Answer Submiting

Tags: file-upload

This time i'm going to participate in Google CodeJam for the first time.. I don't know how to submit a output and i cant understand the guidelines please help me.
I tried to upload a text file containing the answers for small input but it won't accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, it is late, but for the next codejam and other coding competitions -

If you are using bash, then run this on terminal, [assuming the input file has name `input.in` and your code reads everything from `stdin` and prints everything on `stdout`]

```
./myCode < input.in > output.out
```

and then upload the `output.out` file.

** For more details, search for I/O redirection on bash.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for assistance from the CodeJam administrators. Post your query on the CodeJam forum they can guide you well. Plus the response time is also pretty good.

Secondly you mentioned that your text file was not accepted. In that case, what was the error?

Comment: Thank You.. I had a spacing problem that's why it wasn't accepted.